# Unity -3D: StartCoroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

any way i can make this code print "attacking" and than for 2 seconds then print it again and so on. this script just waits for 2 seconds the first time. and then keeps printing it with every frame

```
public class ZombieAI : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
            StartCoroutine(time());
        
    }

    IEnumerator time()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        Debug.Log("Attacking");

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Put a while loop in the coroutine or have it call itself. You’re calling it every frame atm

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by doing this

```
public class ZombieAI : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
            StartCoroutine(time());
        
    }

    IEnumerator time()
    {
        Debug.Log("Attacking");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        StartCoroutine(time());

    }
}
```

You have to start the coroutine from inside the coroutine. However, if you want to implement this WITHOUT coroutines, do this:

```
public class ZombieAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer = 0;
    public float attackTimer = 2;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= attackTimer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Attacking!");
            timer = 0;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Coroutines can cause headaches, but use whichever one you want :)

Comment: thanks. the time.delta time method works . but the coroutine  because m calling it in update not start. any way to use it with start

Comment: Imho a loop in the coroutine would be more appropriate than recursion since you wouldn't have the overhead of beginning a new coroutine each time and could keep a reference to the original coroutine if desired. I agree that it's worth considering using timers instead of coroutines though.

Comment: @AmineMo You can use the coroutine in `Start()` or the timer in `Update()`. Neither would make sense the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do **not** put `StartCoroutine()` in `Update()`. That will begin a new coroutine every frame.

Apart from that, you just need to put the action inside a loop, e.g. a `for` loop. If you want it to keep looping indefinitely until you manually stop the coroutine, you can use:

```
public class ZombieAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() // Or anywhere that will only be called once when you want to start the coroutine)
    {
        StartCoroutine(time());
    }

    IEnumerator time()
    {
        while( true ) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            Debug.Log("Attacking");
        }
    }
}
```